# vim: replace n strings with another strings

Tags: replace

After reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338794/vim-regex-replace-with-n-characters, I've known how to replace tabs by spaces:

```
:%s/^\v(\t)*/\=repeat(repeat(' ',4),strlen(submatch(0)))/g
```

The command above allows me to replace n tabs at the beginning of each line with n four-spaces.

Now I want to inverse it: replace n four-spaces with n tabs, I think the command should be `:%s/^\v(    )*/\=repeat("\t",strlen(submatch(0)))/g`, but it doesn't work: if there is one four-space, it will be replaced by four tabs after executing the command.

Besides, is it possible to get the length of tab of vim so that I can make the command as below?

```
:%s/^\v(\t)*/\=repeat(repeat(' ',getSizeOfTab()),strlen(submatch(0)))/g
```

ATTENTION: I only want to replace the spaces at the beginning of each line.

Comment: @Mass  `\w`? I only want to replace the spaces at the beginning of each line. `:%s/^ \{4}/\t/g` can only replace the first 4 spaces, if there are 8 spaces, it won't work.

Comment: Sorry, no idea what I was thinking.  check out `s/\(^\s*\)\@<= \{4}/\t/g`

Comment: @Mass  I think you can make this as an answer and explain how it works, I ll accept it. I don't understand what `@<=` is.

Comment: @Yves See `:help /\@<=`

Comment: Doesnt `:retab` already solve most of this problem?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble   `:retab` will process all of tabs, but I only want to replace the tabs at the beginning of each line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a simple:

```
%s/\s\{4\}/\t/g
```

that matches 4 spaces and replaces them by a single tab.

If you want it to only appy to the beginning of the line, this should work:

```
%s/\(^\s*\)\@<=\(\s\{4\}\)/\t/g
```

That uses a zero-width assertion to make sure it always matches Spaces at the beginning of a line.

The other question: If you want to know the length of a tab you can access the `'tabstop'` setting. However, since it usually depends on the position where the tab is on the screen, you might want to check the `strdisplaywidth()` function.

Comment: I think it would be better to use plain space characters rather than `\s`. You don't want to replace 4 *tabs* with a single tab. (And yes, I've worked with codebases where this might actually make a difference ;) )

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the command you've already tried is that you're calculating the number of tabs to add by using the length of the entire match. So if you have 4 spaces, which has a length of 4, you use 4 tabs. You can fix this simply by dividing the length by 4. In order not to confuse the `/` division operator with the `/` characters used for separating the `:substitute` command, you will need to use a different character for the latter (See `:help E146`):

```
 :%s@^\v( )+@\=repeat("\t",strlen(submatch(0))/4)@g
           ^                                  ^^
```

N.B. I made one other change to your command: switching the `*` for a `+`. There's no need to replace no spaces with no tabs!